# Department X person is controlled by Department Y person

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, notin

I have 3 tables Employee, Project and Workson, Sample data is:

**Employee:**

```
SocialSecurityNo   Department_No

121212              1
456789              2
666666              2
444444              2
```

**Workson**

```
ESSn              Projectno

121212             5000
456789             1000
456789             2000
666666             1000
666666             2000
666666             3000
666666             4000
666666             5000
666666             6000
```

**Project:**

```
ProjectNumber  Dnum

1000           5
2000           5
3000           5
4000           4
5000           1
6000           4
```

I have to check that Employee with SocialSecurityNo x is selected for Dno y but he is working on a project assigned for department z.

I have written a query for it, My query is working finding all the SSn which are working are selected for department x and working for department x, I am trying to do the opposite, but when I apply `NOT IN` on a subquery then it also give me those social security numbers which have no data in the workson table

Below is my query:

```
Select E.SocialSecurityNo FROM EMPLOYEE E WHERE E.SocialSecurityNo NOT IN 

(Select E.SocialSecurityNo From 

EMPLOYEE E Join WORKSON W ON E.SocialSecurityNo=W.ESSn 

Join PROJECT P ON E.Department_No=P.Dnum 

Where W.ProjectNumber=P.Projectno);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select e.*, p.*
from employee e
inner join workson w on w.essn = e.socialsecurityno
inner join project p on p.projectnumber = w.projectno
where p.dnum <> e.department_no
```

This brings all employee/project pairs where the department of the employee does not match that of the project.

Side note: I would recommend adjusting the names of the columns across the tables, so the schema is easier to understand. There is no reason why a social security number would be called `essn` in one table and `socialsecurityno` in another; same goes for `projectnumber` vs `projectno` and `dnum` vs `department_no`.

Comment: I was reading from the Book that `This create problems when some real-world concept is used in different roles (meanings) in the same relation`